# Getting variable class name of JavaScript from Laravel blade loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am in trouble with getting specific variable javascript class name from Laravel loop.I tried to get it from html data but I got only the first data info of loop.

Here is my blade

```
            @foreach($myanmarmenus as $myanmarmenu)
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="menu">
                        <img src="{{ '/images/menus/'. $myanmarmenu->image }}" class="menuimg">
                        <p class="menutitle">{{$myanmarmenu->title}}  <span class="menuprice">{{$myanmarmenu->price}} <span id="kyat">Ks</span> </span>

                        </p>
                        <p class='menudescription'>
                            {{$myanmarmenu->description}}
                        </p>
                               <span class="menushop">
                                @foreach($myanmarmenu->shops as $shop)
                                {{$shop->name}}
                                 @endforeach
                                </span>
                        <!-- spinner -->
                      <div class="custom_spinner  {{$myanmarmenu->title . $myanmarmenu->id}}" data-spinnerclass="{{$myanmarmenu->id}}">
                          <div class="input-group">
                             <span class="input-group-btn">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm  btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="quant[2]">
                                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                             </button>
                             </span>
                             <input type="text" name="quant[2]" class="form-control input-sm input-number" value="1" min="1" max="1000" id="spinnerval-{{$myanmarmenu->title . $myanmarmenu->id}}">
                             <span class="input-group-btn">
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger  btn-sm btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[2]">
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                              </button>
                             </span>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                        <!-- spinner -->
                        <!-- add -->
                        <div  class="spinner_btn {{$myanmarmenu->title . $myanmarmenu->id}}" data-addclass="{{$myanmarmenu->id}}">Add Item</div>
                        <!-- add -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

And this is js

```
$('.spinner_btn').click(function () {
    var spinner = $(".custom_spinner").data('spinnerclass');
    alert(spinner);
});
```

## my actual purpose is to get the specific class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
$('.spinner_btn').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        var spinner = $(this).siblings(".custom_spinner").data('spinnerclass');
        alert(spinner);
    });
});
```